# Set up MySQL Database dump onto local computer

Tags: mysql, database, dump

I have a file called database.dmp that is the mysql dump from the server last night.  User is probably root.

I want to create a local copy on my computer 'MARK-PC' (I definitely do not overwrite the live database on the server).

1. What is the best command to do this?
   1a. Can I use that command from the microsoft windows command prompt? I am not that familiar with the mysqldump command line and don't want to screw anything up.
2. Will I need to have root access?
3. If I set it up with another user/password, what issues will I run into if any?

Comment: What are you running for a local server?

Comment: The answers all depend on how the dump was created. You'll need to look at the file and determine whether it has `create table` commands and what account(s) it requires.

Comment: I don't know.  I'm new here so I will have to find out.

Comment: Step 1 is probably to try [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and restore from your backup on a local MySQL server.